# In-house DNS Records not caching or propogating

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, internal-dns, dns-zone

We have a in-house DNS managed by our internal IT. We have to request them for any DNS related queries. Recently i asked them to configure a sub-domain i.e. idc.godrej.com

My team uses AWS cloud so i created a zone idc.godrej.com on Route53 and gave our IT name-servers.

I got confirmation that they have successfully updated Zone file. Its been a week after same update but still NS Propagation doesn't seem to reflect on multiple locations, https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/idc.godrej.com

I looked up here, http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=idc.godrej.com to check for records but it results in query error.

I also tried, http://dns.squish.net/traverses/8675e098707bf945732a99e727e17f18
which says there's exception + error.

Can someone please help to debug this in order to request our IT. I'm making list of things that could be possibly wrong. So far i have,

1. Decrease TTL
2. Check SOA Update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Query the actual authoritative nameservers, follow the chain of delegations. (`dig +trace +add ...` etc).

Long answer:

The delegation for `godrej.com` is a mess.

The nameservers for the parent zone (`com`) say:

```
godrej.com.             172800  IN      NS      lilly.godrej.co.in.
godrej.com.             172800  IN      NS      aster.godrej.co.in.
```

But if you query one of the authoritative servers they say:

```
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-804.awsdns-36.net.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-1318.awsdns-36.org.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-125.awsdns-15.com.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-332.awsdns-41.com.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      aster.godrej.co.in.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-1869.awsdns-41.co.uk.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-1516.awsdns-61.org.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-830.awsdns-39.net.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      lilly.godrej.co.in.
godrej.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns-1886.awsdns-43.co.uk.
```

That looks like the combination of the above (lilly,aster) as well as presumably two sets of Route53 nameservers (you normally get a set of four nameservers).

If you query `lilly.godrej.co.in` or `aster.godrej.co.in` about `godrej.com` they appear to generally work they but they don't acknowledge the existence of `idc.godrej.com`.

If you query the Route53 servers about `godrej.com` they answer with `REFUSED` (the reason why I do this is because the actual observed `NS` entries are for `godrej.com`).
Some (one set, presumably) of the Route53 servers do appear to work for `idc.godrej.com`, though.

All in all, the problem appears completely unrelated to caching or "propagation" (a term which makes limited sense regarding DNS, typically used to refer to cache expiration), instead it seems that the delegation has been done incorrectly;  messing up the `NS` records for `godrej.com` rather than delegating `idc.godrej.com`.